# Error Creating Handle C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, forms, handle

I have this pesky error with my program when I go to call a new instance of my loader form.

The function of this form is to take a list of files from the previous form and allow loading of each file based on a hotkey being pressed.

I cannot understand why I am getting the Handler exception, as a handler is assigned right up to `private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;` within the `.Designer.cs` file. Afterwards it throws an exception. I've done a fair bit of searching online and all I tend to come up with in regards to this exception is memory issues. I haven't come across any evidence to indicate this; I am quite stumped.

Here is the class code:

```
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    private BackgroundWorker documentHandler;
    private readonly List<string> files;

    private bool wait;
    private readonly string fileDirectory;
    private string previousFile;
    private string currentFile;
    private string nextFile;
    private int position;

    //Form Constructor
    public FileLoader(string directory, string[] filesToLoad)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        files = new List<string>();
        this.files.AddRange(filesToLoad);
        this.fileDirectory = directory;
    }

    //WorkerSetup
    public void WorkerSetup()
    {
        documentHandler = new BackgroundWorker();

        documentHandler.DoWork += documentHandler_DoWork;
        documentHandler.RunWorkerCompleted += documentHandler_RunWorkerCompleted;

        this.HotKeyManager(true);
        this.FileManager(null);

        documentHandler.RunWorkerAsync(files[0]);
    }

    //ActionMethods
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
        {
            int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();

            if (id == 1)
            {
                this.FileManager(false);
                wait = false;
            }
            if (id == 2)
            {
                this.FileManager(true);
                wait = false;
            }
            if (id == 3)
            {
                documentHandler.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        this.PreProcessMessage(ref m);
    }
    private void HotKeyManager(bool register)
    {
        var regUnreg = register ? 1 : 2;

        switch (regUnreg)
        {
            case 1:
                RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1, 0x0004, 0x25); //Left Key
                RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 2, 0x0004, 0x27); //Right Key
                RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 3, 0x0004, 0x1B); //Esc Key
                break;
            case 2:
                UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1);
                UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 2);
                UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 3);
                break;
        }
    }
    private void FilePosition()
    {
        if (position <= 0)
        {
            this.position = 0;
            this.previousFile = files[position];
            this.currentFile = files[position];
            this.nextFile = files[position + 1];
        }
        else if (position == files.Count)
        {
            this.previousFile = files[position - 1];
            this.currentFile = files[position];
            this.nextFile = files[position];

            documentHandler.CancelAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            this.previousFile = files[position - 1];
            this.currentFile = files[position];
            this.nextFile = files[position + 1];
        }

    }
    private void SetupLabels()
    {
        labelPrevious.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.previousFile) ? "On First" : previousFile;
        labelCurrent.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.currentFile) ? "Error" : previousFile;
        labelNext.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.nextFile) ? "On Last" : previousFile;
    }

    //Controller
    private void FileManager(bool? increment)
    {
        if (increment == true)
        {
            position++;
        }
        else if (increment == false)
        {
            position--;
        }

        this.FilePosition();
        this.SetupLabels();
    }

    //Workers
    private void documentHandler_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var adobeProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Acrobat.exe", this.fileDirectory +   "\\" + currentFile + ".pdf");
        var adobeProcess = new Process { StartInfo = adobeProcessInfo };

        adobeProcess.Start();

        while (wait)
        this.SetupLabels();
    }
    private void documentHandler_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message, "Error");
        }

        this.HotKeyManager(false);
        this.Close();
    }
```

and here is the stack ouput:

> PDFInformationExtraction.exe!PDFInformationExtraction.FileLoader.HotKeyManager(bool register) Line 85   C#
>       PDFInformationExtraction.exe!PDFInformationExtraction.FileLoader.WorkerSetup() Line 47 + 0xd bytes  C#
>       PDFInformationExtraction.exe!PDFInformationExtraction.FormExtract.ButtonLoaderClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 122 + 0xa bytes C#
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0x7f bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0xa2 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mevent) + 0xac bytes 
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button, int clicks) + 0x2d1 bytes 
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x93a bytes 
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x127 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x20 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x13 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x31 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x64 bytes 
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x287 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x16c bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x61 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm) + 0x31 bytes
>       PDFInformationExtraction.exe!PDFInformationExtraction.Program.Main() Line 18 + 0x1d bytes   C#
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) + 0x6d bytes
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x2a bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x63 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x2c bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

**EDIT:** 
Turns out my method to listen for hot keys was formatted wrong:

- `this.PreProcessMessage(ref m);` should have been `base.WndProc(ref m);`

Comment: IIRC, this is the typical error you get when you exceeded the amount of UI stuff you can ever create in a winforms application. It's like Warcraft 2 when you had 7 AIs against you and they had endless gold and then it came a certain time in the game when you couldn't create any more units unless you started killing the computers'. It might be time to leave the archaic dinosaur behind and embrace any of the modern, beautiful, hardware-rendered, vector-based, more-with-less, XAML-based technologies.

Comment: I only have about 35~ UI elements running at a given time. I haven't seen any indication of UI elements causing the issue in my memory profiling /:

Comment: "Exceeded the amount of UI stuff"??  Total nonsense.  "Hardware-rendered, vector-based, more-with-less".. again total car salesmen nonsense.  If you like WPF/XAML.. then use it.  It isn't earth shattering technology.